# Is it possible to change the fonts,colors and other css properties of the calender in XDSoft datetime picker

Tags: html, jquery, css, datetimepicker

I want to customize the look of XDSoft calender.

I wanted to change the background and text color of the past dates of the current month to be white and grey respectively. Similarly for the current and future dates it should be grey and Navy blue respectively.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.